# Detection of flow file lag in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

We are using Apache Nifi for our data ingestion purpose from database. We have seen that the flow file started accumulating prior to certain processor due to slow consumption of processor or any other bug.

How can we detect this in realtime via alert/notification if flow file count exceeded (or flow file lag) to certain threshold? Please suggest

Comment: what about queue threshold and backpressure features that will color your queue to yellow and read when it's in bad condition: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Backpressure

Comment: also here is a nice article how to do monitoring through api: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/NiFi-REST-API-FlowFile-Count-Monitoring/ta-p/244208#comment-170948

Comment: also you are able to see all queues in nifi: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#monitoring

Comment: I like what you have shared. I wanted to decouple the monitoring from nifi tool. I am able to bring the metrics of nifi on prometheus DB. Now I want to setup alert on the same. Can you please help with the metrics to do the same?

Please share any reference on Grafana/Prometheus based monitoring and alert.

Answer (score 0):

to monitor alerts through api use following endpoint:

`/nifi-api/flow/bulletin-board?limit=10`

the api description you can find here:
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html

---

if you need something else to monitor:

- just find where you see it in nifi UI
- open devtools in browser and trace the api cals in network tab

for example "Nifi Bulletin Board" calling following api to get alerts:

[image]